# Phonegap (iOS) keyboard breaks viewport on orientation change

Tags: ios, css, cordova, orientation, viewport

**Later edit**: issue was jquery mobile.

I have an app built with phonegap and jQuery mobile. Everything works perfect until input is focused and keyboard appears. After this, if I'll switch orientation, viewport is broken.

Example :

1. Home screen (portrait)

[image: Home screen (portrait)]

2. Home screen, changed orientation

[image: Home screen, changed orientation]

3. Home screen (portrait) with input focused

[image: Home screen (portrait) with input focused]

4. Home screen (landscape) after input was focused

[image: Home screen (landscape) after input was focused]

As you can see in #4, viewport is broken.

I'm using fixed viewport size (width=640, user-scalable=no). Also tried to use scale programmatically on orientation change, change viewport on orientation change, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!